# Trying to edit html table data with python data (ajax get method?)

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, html, ajax

I am building a program for ranking people (don't ask) and I think I am facing a beginners issue- I have a desired value generated in python which I wish to make the content of an html table.

The table is a leader board, which is determined by finding the person with the highest score (obv). I have a list of the top 10 people, and I am now wishing to put that into an html table. Ideally, I would like this to edit the actual html file, so that when one user generates the table it will save it for the next. (I will change the generateTable function to be a button)

I have tried using beautiful soup with no luck, I read the documentation however I could not seem to find the solution.

Basically, I am just trying to call a python variable with ajax. I can do the reverse, however. I am new at programming if you can't tell.

I am running a python flask server on my local network, and I am using the google sheets api as a makeshift database.

server.py:

```
@app.route("/leader", methods=['POST'])
def leader():
    name_and_score = []
    length = int(changedata.next_available_row(2))
    for x in range(2,length):
        time.sleep(1.1)
        name_and_score.append((int(changedata.index(x,7)), str((changedata.index(x,1)))))
    print str(name_and_score) + ' <--- This is everybody'
    leaderboard = nlargest(10, name_and_score)
    return str(leaderboard) + ' <--- These are top 10'
```

leaderboard.html

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="static/css/scoreboard.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function generateTable() {
        $.ajax({
            method: 'POST',
            url: "http://10.0.1.36:5000/leader",
            success: function(response) {
                console.log(response)
             },
            error: function(response) {
                console.error(response)
            }
        });
    }
    window.onload=generateTable;

</script>
<p class = holder>Boys</p>

<table style="width:30%">
  <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Score</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id = 'person1'> Person </td>
    <td id = 'person1_score'>45000</td>
  <tr>
    <td id = 'person2'> Person </td>
    <td id = 'person2_score'>45000</td>
  </tr>
      <tr>
    <td id = 'person3'> Person </td>
    <td id = 'person3_score'>50000</td>
  </tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated in making a python variable the string in its respective cell in html.

str(leaderboard) looks like:  [(26316, 'Name'), (6250, 'Name'), (6667, 'Name'), (6250, 'Name'), (4545, 'Name'), (36364, 'Name'), (46154, 'Name')]

- I have omitted the names however they are distinct values.

Answer (score 0):

Use json.dumps() instead of str(leaderboard) so you could parse it back in the HTML.

```
return make_response(json.dumps(leaderboard),200)
```

give your table some id:

```
<table id="myleaderboard" style="width:30%">...</table>
```

Then, parse it and populate table:

```
function generateTable() {
    $.ajax({
        method: 'POST',
        url: "http://10.0.1.36:5000/leader",
        success: function(response) {
            console.log(response);
            try {
              let res = JSON.parse(response);
              let table = document.getElementById("myleaderboard");
              //clear table
              table.innerHTML = "";
              //populate
              for (let i = 0;i < res.length; i++) {
                 const tr = document.createElement("tr");
                 const td1 = document.createElement("td");
                 const td2 = document.createElement("td");
                 td1.innerHTML = res[i][0]; //score
                 td2.innerHTML = res[i][1]; //name
                 tr.appendChild(td1);
                 tr.appendChild(td2);
                 table.appendChild(tr);
              }
            } catch(e){}
         },
        error: function(response) {
            console.error(response)
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Thank you a lot for your response. I edited the post as you requested. However, when I tried to run this code I got the error 'AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'to_json''. I suspect this has to do with the list leaderboard being a list of lists. I will attempt to solve it now and let you know. Thanks so much!

Comment: it's ok. i thought you were using pandas for nlargest(). the last edit should work for you. using json.dumps()

Comment: OK, that worked in generating the table, however all values in the table are 'undefined'. I think this has to do with the lines trying to get the name and the score. (.name and .score) as I don't think the attribute score and name was defined.

Comment: td1.innerHTML = res[i][0]; //score
td2.innerHTML = res[i][1]; //name